# Installed Xubuntu on XP system but cannot boot it

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu on a Windows XP machine. I left Windows XP on the machine, and made a new logical drive, E, to which I installed Xubuntu. During the installation, I was asked to install "grub" something-or-other that would let me choose which OS I used at boot time. I tried several times to install that, but failed every time, so went on to finish the install without "grub."

I then got a message saying I would have to load Xubuntu "manually" by means of some kind of kernel operation. I have no idea how that works. Now, when I startup the computer it loads Windows and ignores Xubuntu.

I have tried to change the boot order, but the only relevant option is "Hard Disk," which automatically loads the OS on C. I cannot select my new logical drive E as the boot drive.

How can I load Xubuntu?

Comment: Did you install Xubuntu from inside Windows XP using WUBI.EXE? **Please edit the original question** with new information.

Answer (score 0):

grub is the program that starts Ubuntu. It needs to be installed and the partition needs to be marked bootable. Otherwise your computer will ignore it.

This is a common issue when someone installs Windows for instance, so how to fix it has been answered before: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Will all the methods that work for Ubuntu work for Xubuntu? Also, I understand that some Grub help utilities do not work with a 32-bit microprocessor.

Comment: It's the same operating system, but with a different desktop environment. So yes, installing them and bootloading, etc, is identical.